# strtok gives empty string or something I don't know

Tags: c, char, strtok, arrays

I have the following source-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char string[100];
    printf("Give me some text. \n");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);

    char delimiter[]=" ";
    char *erg;

    erg=strtok(string, delimiter);

    while(erg != NULL){
        printf("Wort: %s \n", erg);

        erg=strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I for example put in the text "abc def", the program is working like I want it to work. It print out the words "abc" and "def".
But when I put in the text "abc def ", it prints out "abc", "def" and "". 
I don't want to print out the last empty "". 
Can someone please tell me how to filter that ?

Gruß, Andre

Comment: `char delimiter[]=" \n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you need to get rid of the last `\n` read by `fgets()` in `fgets(string, 100, stdin);`

You can do this in many ways, like

1. include the `\n` in your delimiter list. `" \n"`, for example.
2. manually check the length of string, and at the last position, replace the `\n` with a `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` gets a whole string along with the `\n` character which you press after entering the string.So use

```
string[strlen(string)-1]='\0';
```

to replace the `\n` in `string` with a `\0`.